# How to update .ism and .rul files when moving to a new version?

Tags: installshield, basic-msi

I have basic msi project created with InstallShield 2015
It’s .ism and .rul files include many values which are changed whenever our software has new version which is quite often.
I have list of items needed to be updated every version and all being done manually but using InstallShield UI.

I have a script that use InstallShield automation to update ProductVersion, ProductCode, ProductName etc. but what about all kind of registry settings, strings, component destination etc. ?

Comment: What about them - are you running into limitations with the automation interface, have you just not written the code yet, or are you looking for alternative approaches that involve fewer changes?

Answer (score 0):

we are runing in the same kind of problems at my work, to overcome it, we automated search and replace in the .ism (saved in XML) and .rul at build time.